# Why is my text auto aligning left in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, text, swiftui, alignment

I'm new to Swift and usually when I add a text in a VStack or an HStack it adds the text to the middle of the screen but now it's on the left for some reason. Why is that and how can I fix it?

```
  var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text("Welcome Back").font(.system(size: 32, weight: .heavy))
                Text("Sign in to continue").font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                FormField(value: $email, icon: "mail", placeholder: "Email")
                FormField(value: $password, icon: "lock", placeholder: "Password", isSecure: true)
                Button(action: {print("")}){
                    Text("Sign In")
                        .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .modifier(ButtonModifiers())
                }
                HStack{
                    Text("New?")
                    Text("Create a new account")
                }
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFAOF.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a `VStack` `alignment` is set to `.center`, but it looks like you set the `alignment` of your second `VStack` to `leading`, to fix that:

Change:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading){ 
    // your code ...
}
```

to

```
VStack(alignment: .center){ 
    // your code ...
}
```